# This YouTube channel is creating videos based on SO questions. Is this ok?

Tags: discussion, copyright, copyright-infringement

Check out this channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaZL4eLD7a30Fa8QI-sRi_g/videos

Each of these videos shows a woman presenting a problem. It's the same generic opening and closing each time while it cuts away to a screenshot of [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) with a copy and pasted question and answer from Stack Overflow.

This just seems to be trying to make money off of SO posts, take traffic away from SO, and honestly it's actually more difficult to consume this way than looking at Stack Overflow itself.

Is this considered copyright infringement?

Comment: *it's actually more difficult to consume this way than looking at stack overflow itself.*  I would only be concerned when that changes to *it's actually much easier to consume this way than looking at stack overflow itself.*

Comment: They make an attempt to provide attribution, but it is far from sufficient. They don't provide a link or ID to the question or to the authors. Transcribing back to text and using a search engine is the only way to find the Stack Overflow page in question. There is [a lot of machine generated content](https://odysee.com/@eevblog:7/eevblab-99-spam-bot-youtube-space:6) on YouTube these days. Don't fall into the trap of opening videos from, e.g. "Future Unity", with hyperbole titles like *"Scientists terrifying new discoveries on Jupiter after 43 years"*

Comment: cont' - At least we avoid having to look at [shocked faces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln1qbgZz_TQ&t=14m20s) for those channels. They have understood that clickbait titles (with proper grammar) of the form ***"XXXXXX discovers mysterious structure in YYYYYY!"***, ***XXXXXX’s terrifying new discovery shocks the entire YYYYYY industry***, and ***"The new discovery in XXXXXX that scares YYYYYY!"***  are much more effective.

Comment: (Scratch the transcribe part - the titles of the Stack Overflow pages are in the title of the videos.)

Comment: Correction: each of these videos shows the exact same footage of a woman, in-between which a unique question and answer are presented. Ridiculous how this channel has 27k subscribers.

Comment: Re *"more difficult to consume this way"*: They could improve it be using a (computer) synthesised voice. An example is the mentioned "Future Unity"; it is very good (good intonation, etc.). Though it would probably sound very strange for the average Stack Overflow question with code and/or command lines.

Comment: [A sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091167/update-a-column-in-table-using-sqlloader) from the channel mentioned in the question.