# YouTube channel scraping Q&A from Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing, attribution, creative-commons

There is this [horrible YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/@peterschneiderQandA/videos) scraping Q&A from Stack Exchange without attribution to the author of either question or answers, and no links to the original post.

[Stack Exchange licenses its content](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) under [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)

> Under the following terms: Attribution — You must give appropriate
> credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were
> made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that
> suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.
>
> ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you
> must distribute your contributions under the same license as the
> original.

I think both the Attribution and ShareAlike  clause are violated here.

Is this abuse or allowed?

Comment: Actually, while I find it highly problematic, I've checked out a few of their videos, and the video description contains a link back to the source, the username of the asker + answerers, and a (broken) link to the license. IANAL, but I'm not sure if that would qualify as a violation given that they include a link back to the source. That said, it may be against YouTube's policies

Comment: Almost all scapers, incl. on YouTube, don't provide sufficient attribution (either it is missing or incomplete). The company [gave up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413407) a long time ago. It is busy work on our side. Perhaps a license troll could pick it up?

Comment: Related: *[This YouTube channel is creating videos based on SO questions. Is this ok?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381384/)*

Comment: @rhermans "There's this horrible youtube channel..." jeez! That's a little harsh, isn't it? Calling them "horrible" for one thing! I've got anger problems, but I've never judged anyone that badly over one little thing.

Comment: [Its autogeneration is messed up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQgvd7OhYLY&t=1m18s).

Comment: Even the license link is broken ([sample video description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rtB3w6e8Ys)): `https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)CC`. Perhaps YouTube requires a space after the URL? It should be [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing). But attribution seems to be correct.

Comment: Re *"without attribution to the author of either question or answers, and no links to the original post."*: **** ***I dispute this*** ****. [For this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rtB3w6e8Ys) there are links to both all of the three authors and the question. Though "https://" is left out for the author links and the question link is wrapped in weird text. Is there a counterexample?